# Exists property is crashing script

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

I have some code that looks for a specified key in an onscreen keyboard, and clicks it when found. I'm running into an issue where sometimes the `Exists` property doesn't exist, and it's crashing my test.

```
function findKey(propertyName, character, shiftMode) {
  var keyboard = getKeyboard()

  var key = keyboard.findChild(propertyName, character, 2)

  if (key.Exists) { // Crashes on this line.
    keyboard.set_ShiftMode(shiftMode)
    key.Click()

    return true
  }

  return false
}
```

The really crazy thing is that when I add a breakpoint to that line and check it out in the inspectors, the Locals inspector has the property, but Watch List says it doesn't exist. Additionally, this isn't super consistent. So far it has either happened on the first or second character in the string.

**Locals**

[image: Locals]

**Watch List**

[image: Watch List]

**Error Log**

[image: Error Log]

What could be causing the property to not exist in some situations of the code? I thought that `Exists` [is always on anything returned](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/test-objects/members/common-for-all/findchild-method.html#result-value) by `findChild` specifically so you can know if anything was returned.

Comment: Even if it's `undefined` it shouldn't crash. What error are you getting ?

Comment: What happens in getKeyboard()?

Comment: Probably because `key` is undefined. Have you tried `if (key && key.Exists) { }` ?

Comment: We can't help you without an error log and an [mcve]

Comment: Try also refactoring that line to use bracket notation instead of dot notation: `if (key['Exists']) { }`. Also, depending on what `findChild` returns, you may add a check: `if (typeof key === 'object' && key['Exists']) { }`

Comment: I've added the error log. @Wimanicesir there a are few different pages that have the keyboard, so that function will search for whichever one is active and return the keyboard from the page.

Comment: @kemicofa `if (key && key.Exists)` did not work because it is still of the same class as the others that do have `Exists`. Other properties and functions still exist, and its class type is what I'm expecting.

Comment: My guess (and this is a guess, not a real answer) is that @kemicofa is right.  I don't understand your response to his comment.  If keyboard.findChild(...) returns "undefined" or "null" then your code will crash.  What is the value of "key" at the point where your code crashes?  Is it defined?  Non-null?

Comment: @Duncan The object is defined. Just missing that property. It still has other properties and functions that others keys with `Exist` have.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the Visible or VisibleOnScreen properties instead?

Also, you should try to record to KeyWord Test, and then convert it to script.

Comment: Recording the test wouldn't give me the results I want. There is a function that receives a string and breaks it down into characters and uses this function to enter that character, if it can be found. It's designed to be used in many places, so it has to be dynamic.